# Cumulative sum with a reset

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I want to use the cumsum function of pandas and reset this cumulative series when a condition is fulfilled. For example i have this df :

```
       o  values
   0   1       4
   1   1       4
   2   2       2
   3   2       5
   4   3       1
   5   3      10
```

and where the value of 'o' is +1 i want to reset the cumulative sum. I know I can find the condition with :

```
s = df['o'].diff() == 1
```

which return a boolean series where a row ['o'] is + 1.

How can i continue to have the following result :

```
       o  values  cum_sum
   0   1       4        4
   1   1       4        8
   2   2       2        2
   3   2       5        7
   4   3       1        1
   5   3      10       11
```

Thank for your help and your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df['cumsum']=df.groupby('o').cumsum()
```

Output:

```
df
   o  values  cumsum
0  1       4       4
1  1       4       8
2  2       2       2
3  2       5       7
4  3       1       1
5  3      10      11
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
df['cum_sum'] = df.groupby('o').transform('cumsum')
```

output:

```
    o   values  cum_sum
0   1   4       4
1   1   4       8
2   2   2       2
3   2   5       7
4   3   1       1
5   3   10      11
```